# Resize webview when I show the keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, keyboard

I created a webview (xamarin - Android) but when I press on a textbox the keyboard is positioned above the webview and there is a button positioned at the bottom of the page. The webview is not resized. On Chrome the button is on top of the keyboard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize` to your `Activity` attribute:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, 
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work! The application compiles but the button doesn't go up.  Instead of this `public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity`  I have this `public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity`

Comment: @Luk4, could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo?

Comment: @Luk4, since you are using `Xamarin.Forms` project, where did you use `WebView`? PCL or native Android? Please post your code.

Comment: Ésta solución funciona sólo con controles nativos de Xamarin, dentro de un WebView no tiene efecto alguno

Answer (score 2):

Another solution documented here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85024/webview-doesnt-get-resized-or-panned-when-soft-keyboard-is-overlayed

In the constructor in App.xaml.cs:

```
using AndroidSpecific = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

namespace yournamespace
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        //your init code
    }
}
}
```